# Is this some kind of backflush septic filter?

Tags: septic

Filter is connected to two white PVC pipes:

[image]

But it also has this tiny black hose that sends water to tank when pump is engaged. See this picture:

[image]

Is it some kind of backflush filter (similar to R.O. systems) so that waste water going to leech field is of higher quality?

Also, is it safe to assume that this filter is not between two tanks but rather between last tank and leech field? I am confused because filter access is built exactly between two tank lids.

Comment: If you don't have the plans of your system, you should get a copy from the local office that did the permitting and/or inspection of the system when it was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a disc filter for a drip field/system. If I'm correct, the thin tub should send "clean" water to drip lines to disperse it into the surrounding soil, so I would expect it is after the last tank.

[image]

I am not endorsing any particular product, but these are the sites I found that seemed relevant and were helpful to me to better understand what this setup seems to be:

https://betterthanseptic.blogspot.com/2016/03/aquaklear-headworks.html

https://jtsepticco.com/drip-systems-what-are-they-and-do-you-need-one

Comment: Thanks, the picture you found is helpful and it starts to make sense. But doesn't picture state that small black hose goes back to pre treatment (i.e. effluent holding tank) and not leech field? From picture I understood that black hose is sending "dirty" water from backflusing when solenoid closes. My filter is sending water back non stop to holding tank whenever pump is running, so I wonder if solenoid is stuck open. Though, I am not sure I have solenoid as my septic controller does not have wires for that.